# Can Apache/httpd totally block requests made directly to the server's IP address (as opposed to a hostname)?

Tags: php, apache, centos

I'm using httpd on Centos with name-based virtual hosts and I would like to block all traffic which attempts to access the server via its direct IP address, and only serve content if the visitor comes to a valid hostname.

E.g. let's say I host http://example.com on `1.2.3.4`. If a visitor tries to visit http://1.2.3.4, the connection should time out as if the server doesn't exist or is unreachable. If they visit http://example.com, it should serve properly.

How do I configure this in httpd.conf?